# Golang error function arguments too large for new goroutine

Tags: go

I am running a program with go 1.4 and I am trying to pass a large struct to a go function.

```
go ProcessImpression(network, &logImpression, campaign, actualSpent, partnerAccount, deviceId, otherParams)
```

I get this error:

```
runtime.newproc: function arguments too large for new goroutine
```

I have moved to pass by reference which helps but I am wondering if there is some way to pass large structs in a go function.

Thanks,

Comment: Note: There is absolutely no notion of "pass by reference" in Go. You pass pointers by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, none I know of.

I don't think you should be too aggressive tuning to avoid copying, but it appears [from the source](http://golang.org/src/runtime/proc.c#L2199) that this error is emitted when parameters exceed the usable stack space for a new goroutine, which should be kilobytes. The copying overhead is real at that point, especially if this isn't the only time these things are copied. Perhaps some struct either explicitly is larger than expected thanks to a large struct member (1kb array rather than a slice, say) or indirectly. If not, just using a pointer as you have makes sense, and if you're worried about creating garbage, recycle the structs pointed to using [`sync.Pool`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by changing the arguments from

```
func doStuff(prev, next User)
```

to

```
func doStuff(prev, next *User)
```

The answer from @twotwotwo in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28226147/5531595) is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue at processing list of values(`[]BigType`) of big struct:

```
for _, stct := range listBigStcts {
    go func(stct BigType) {
        ...process stct ...
    }(stct) // <-- error occurs here

}
```

Workaround is to replace `[]BigType` with `[]*BigType`